# Change ContextVIew android

Tags: android, layout

it's possible in runtime set another layout in my activity?

How it is possible?

Doing only setContextView(new layout ) it gives a error in execution

Regards

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Did you search about INTENTS in android?

Comment: setContextView(new layout )  or setContentView(R.layout.main); !!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you transition to a new `Activity` rather than calling `setContentView()` again.

If you want to go the route of calling `setContentView()` a second time you will have to re-initialize all of the `Views` in the layout again with `findViewById()` and make sure you don't use or leak old references.

Comment: but if i do a new setContentView the application crash in run time, why?