# One activity uses two or more layout, how do we re-initialize all of the Views to call setContentView a second time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, setcontentview

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875852/change-contextview-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) [antew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309304/antew) says that we must have to re-initialize all of the Views in the layout again with findViewById() and make sure you don't use or leak old references to make a second call of setContentView.

My question is: how do we do the re-initialize?

The following day I found a solution without re-initilize anything:

After more testing, the most easiest solution works, I have put the setContentView inside an event onClick of a buttom

```
public void onButtonChangeLayoutClicked(View v)
{
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
```

Yesterday I was putting the setContentView inside an onRadioButtonClicked and the screen didn't change the layout.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Its almost certain to be the wrong thing to do-  either starting another activity or moving to fragments would be a better idea.

Comment: to reinitialize re assign the view with findviewbyid again simple

Comment: I don't use fragments yet because I'm starting. I'm finding out the bounds at the basics and then go up. I think create a new activity for only change a bunch of widgets is overwork. Change the layout associated to the activity is more efficient in my opinion. Anyway I'm looking for the bounds.